# Symfony Serializer sub-grouping possible?

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

i have following question:
is it possible to create sub-groups for object serialization using jms-serialization-package in Symfony?

example: can i create from this object

```
class Book {
  public string $title;
  public int $releaseYear;
  public int $releaseDay;
  public int $releaseMonth;
}
```

an json-result like this:

```
{
"title": "Example",
"relaseInformation": [
     "releaseYear": 2021,
     "releaseDay": 14,
     "releaseMonth": 08
     ]
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess you could use Handlers ? https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers

Comment: Thats it! Thanks for your help